# Find the number of possible passwords that can be created

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that you are assigned an e-mail account, you need to create your own password.  The format of a password is three digits followed by five uppercase letters such that neither digit nor letter can be repeatedly used.  Find the number of possible passwords that can be created.

a. $5683392000$

b. $947232000$

c. $47361600$

d. $7893600$

Comment: How long is your alphabet, 26?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 10 digits, and 26 letters.

- The digits

For the first digit, there are 10 options.
For the second digit, there are 9 options, because you have used one already.
For the third digit there are 8 options for the same reason.

- The uppercase letters

for the first letter, there are 26 options.
for the second, there are 25, because you have used a letter
...and keep on going until you reach the 5th letter

You can use the rule of multiplication to find the answer.

Hope this helps!

Selena

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than providing complete solution. Also, ask OP for their attempt or what more they know about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).

Comment: Oops, ok I'll remember that next time, thanks!